# How to get column value from database using query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm completely new in using sqlite databases with android.
I want to get value from database using following SQL statement:

```
"SELECT description FROM games WHERE _id =" + categoryID
```

Where categoryID is the position of clicked element in listView (which is also the value of _id column).

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

                String categoryID = new Integer(position).toString();

                final String SELECT_FROM = "SELECT description " + "FROM games "
                        + "WHERE _id = " + categoryID;
                database.query(SELECT_FROM);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SqliteDbActivity.this, ViewAction.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("categoryID", SELECT_FROM);
                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

I know that I should use `database.query()` but how should I correctly write the previous sql statement to get value?

Table looks like:

```
_id description name
1    some1       name1
2    some2       name2       
3    some3       name3
```

Please, help.

Comment: What sort of `Adapter` are you using for your `ListView`?

Comment: @MisterSquonk I'm using `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String categoryID = new Integer(position).toString();

            final String SELECT_FROM = "SELECT description " + "FROM games "
                    + "WHERE _id = " + categoryID;
            Cursor cursor = database.query(SELECT_FROM);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(SqliteDbActivity.this, ViewAction.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("categoryID", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fieldname"));
            intent.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(intent);
```

your `database.query(SELECT_FROM)` will return `cursor`, with the help of cursor you can do your work

Comment: Thaks, but can I pass this value to the next activity using bundle?

Comment: Ok, what should be instead of `"fieldname"`?

Comment: index either 0,1,2... depends on your number of column in your table. cursor.getString(0) will return 1st column value.

Comment: So if I have table as at the question index will be 1? Or I misunderstood you.

Comment: 0 will be your index cursor.getString(0), not 1

Comment: ok, thanks. Now I'm trying to use that, but eclipse says that `The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String)`. How can I write query() correctly?

Comment: use this query("games", new String[]{"description "}, null, null, null, null, null)

Comment: It is great, but now I always get only the first value of "description" column. I need to get the "description" value depending on the value of "name" column. For example, if I click in listview on name1 (first value of "name" column) I need to get the "some1" value of "description" column (the example of table is at the question). If it is not difficult to you, help please.

Comment: cursor.moveNext(), cursor.movePrevious() etc will help you.

Comment: refer http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-sqlite-query-example-selection.html